# Deactivation of the possibility to deactivate 2FA via rescue mode (linux) - 2FA PAM module it doesn't make sense

Tags: security, two-factor-authentication, rescue-mode

I got interested in 2FA to log in for linux os ( PAM google authentificator)

**The problem is that from the rescue boot level it can be easily disabled** which means that if someone has physical access to the machine it doesn't matter.

In that case, in ubuntu in what way can **I deactivate the ability to disable 2FA** or in drastic cases completely remove the ability to use rescue mode?

**Alternatively**, are there any other similar solutions of this type (i.e. 2FA for the system?)

Comment: If someone has physical access to the machine, and you don't have full disk encryption then basically all bets are off. Do you have the disk encrypted?

Comment: The drive is one thing, but someone may know the encryption password (cpu god mode - motherboard backdoor, compomised bios etc ) and the login password. 2FA protects against this much better. I would like to be sure that 2FA will always be active and no one will turn it off